# Difference between PHP Arrays and possible output

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Can someone please provide an explanation on the difference of the two PHP arrays below and how they are used with a possible output?

```
$final['a']['b'] = queryX($conn, $id, 'user');
$final['b'] = queryY($conn, $id, 'visitor');
```

Note that queryX and queryY are functions that contains SQL Queries and returns them as associative arrays.

Comment: Well, the first statement assigns whatever those functions return to an element in an array that is the value of an element of another array, whilst the second assigns it directly to an element in an array.

Comment: Can you provide an in-depth explanation?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what else to add here. Simplifying you can think of the first version to use a two dimensional array, the second a one dimensional. Though as said: that is drastically simplified.

Comment: Please, help me with an example.

Comment: I don't understand what you are actually asking. What exactly is it that you do not understand? Are you familiar with the notation `$final['a']`? Do you understand what it actually says?

Comment: No. That's why I am asking an output of both as an example. Please help

Comment: OK, all fine, we all start to learn at one point. You will learn and understand too, no question. However it makes little sense for us to write complex and long answers in this case. Instead I suggest you simply take a look at the php documentation and what it has to say about arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php I am convinced that will answer your question.

Comment: Despite several searches made on Google to understand this part, I was unable to get an appropriate answer. So, that's why I posted here.

Comment: Sure, no problem. However I did not refer you to searching on google, but to read the good and precise php documentation (which every php programmer has to do anyway), since it actually comes with good examples.

Comment: If you _really_ read that documentation and still have questions or issues you do not understand (which is perfectly fine), then you will have to state what those issues are exactly. We cannot help otherwise.

Comment: to kner kaV pilon ? bous to liki, saye to liki aler..

Comment: How eloquent! And so very fitting here!