# PHP v5 Array Difference

Tags: php, arrays

I have come across two kind of arrays in PHP lately. However, I am unable to understand the main difference. I have a confusion in my mind about what these do. Can someone please enlighten me? Can I return both as associative arrays ?

```
$final['a']['b'] = "";
$final['c'] = "";
```

Comment: I don't get what you understand. First you save an empty value in the second dimension from your array, then an empty value in the first dimension with the key c.

Comment: Disregard the empty quotes. I just put to indicate if I am assigning something.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit with an example ? 
Can both be returned as associative arrays ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between PHP Arrays and possible output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235787/difference-between-php-arrays-and-possible-output)

Comment: You can store anything in an array, including arrays. Using the array subscript syntax in an assignment (`$foo[$index] = $value;`) implicitly makes the left-hand side an array. These two PHP features are already enough to explain above code. Maybe I don't understand your question though, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the first is a 2-dimensional array, the second has only one dimension. The first is an array that contains arrays. This is nothing special, it exists in most (higher) programming and scripting languages.

Maybe it becomes clearer if you create the array with the array keyword:

Your second line would look like this:

```
$final = array(
  "c" => ""
);
```

Your first line like this:

```
$final = array(
  "a" => array(
    "b" => ""
  )
);
```

Comment: Hmm I see. lets say I assign a function which returns an SQL query as a multi-dimensional array. Will be there any difference?

Comment: Difference to what? An array is an array, regardless of what it contains.

Comment: Is 2-dimensional array same as associative array?

Comment: An array is called "associative" if it has non-numeric indizes. It doesn't matter how many dimensions it has.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Please note that this user has asked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235787/difference-between-php-arrays-and-possible-output) which has a similar structue (parameter names, indexes, etc)  and the same lack of details - I don't believe that's a real user asking real questions (I flagged the question just in case)